# matterjs physics not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, polygon, phaser-framework, matter.js, phaserjs

In my game, I have a scenario where (simple) polygons are created dynamically in parts from vertices.

However, I am facing what appears to be a bug with the physics between these Polygons.

Take the below image of 2 polygons (showing vertices ordering via numbers).

[Image of two polygons with vertices listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNlp0.jpg)

I have recreated this example that shows a Polygon in two parts but when they collide together the behaviour is extremely strange, see the video below.

[Video here](https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/159090223/302465756-0eaef56f-7c49-4985-8773-207805a9c4e4.webm?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.YasMjP192SM48TkH4pl-OL4uHv8uTKIIfeRoIuf31fM)

As you can see above, once the two polygons collide one is strangely thrown around.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? This is just one example but I have other polygons also facing the issue.

See below for a codepen recreation including all vertices used etc (using phaser + matter) and some additional information embedded in the pen.

[Codepen Recreation](https://codepen.io/calcue/pen/XWGqPZj)

```js
// vertices of both polygons
 verticesTop = [
    { x: 369.0465076788701, y: 608.8012502894586 },
    { x: 354.8784175468987, y: 556.2317484173886 },
    { x: 307.9626367720781, y: 552.119630436472  },
    { x: 317.73639223252496, y: 477.3301010610348 },
    { x: 244.85158210397867, y: 471.6025839265548 },
    { x: 268.09225309287183, y: 546.1738331583199 },
    { x: 235.62039320960963, y: 622.9079760483232 }
  ];

  verticesBottom = [
    { x: 235.62039320960963, y: 622.9079760483232 },
    { x: 369.0465076788701, y: 608.8012502894586 },
    { x: 387.9793648300112, y: 679.0500177789156 },
    { x: 211.9339970778227, y: 678.8812190919905 }
  ];
```

Comment: maybe the top polygon isn't simple because one vertice is inside the body.

Comment: I believe it is concave (that is still simple right?) but matterjs decomposes that into multiple convex polygons. But can't seem to correctly handle the physics for it.

Comment: I think @ITgoldman is right, since if one remove the second vertice of the top polygon, the physics seem to work again.

Comment: but matterjs should be compatible with concave polygons converted into multiple convex. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: All relevant code should be in the question itself as a [mcve]. Thanks.